# Starting service taking to much time in Android

Tags: android, service

So here's the situation. I've got a login screen (Activity) to my app, and juste after another screen that shows some stuff (another button for now) and starts a service. This service is starting an xmpp connection for the chat.

What I want is when I press connexion on the login screen, the next screen appears and service starts.

But currently, when I press connexion, the login screen stays for about 2s while the next screen starts the service. I know it's the service call slowing everything down because when commented the screen come up fast.

Only the onCreate is coded in the screen and I tried using an AsyncTask too but it didn't change anything:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ecrancoreglayout);

    next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.boutonContinuer);
    next.setOnClickListener(this);

    Intent service_intent = new Intent(this, ChatService.class);
    startService(service_intent);
    //new ConnectWork().execute();
}
```

The service looks like this, initConnection is the function that connect to xmpp and get roster and stuff... :

```
public class ChatService extends Service
{

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    packetListener = new MessageListener();
}

@Override  
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{  
    initConnection();

    handler = new Handler();
    return START_NOT_STICKY;  
}  


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    return null;
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: No ideas ? Maybe there's another way of doing this, a Thread possibly ?

Comment: For anyone who has the same problem, what seems too work is from the onCreate() (if thats where you're doing long tasks) just call a AsyncTask and execute work in it.
The confusion, and apparently i'm not the only one, is that a service runs in the main thread. (it does not have a separate Thread, neither it's own process).